# Board game pathfinding - finding multiple optimal paths

Tags: path-finding

I have a very simple pathfinding task- a board game played on an 8x8 grid, with each square either being passable or not. What I'm looking for is an algorithm which will give me the best n paths to get from some square A to square B (assuming there are any).

I've been looking at A*, but as far as I can see, there's no clear way to extend it to find more than one path.

So, what's critical is that the paths it gives are actually the shortest n paths, that it doesn't miss any. Efficiency is also very important. Could anybody suggest an algorithm that would be appropriate, or point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 3):

Dijkstra's is a good algorithm for most situations like these, but since you're on an 8x8 grid, I'm going to assume that all the distances between each cell are both equal and static. In this case, a BFS (Breadth First Search) should suit you well.

Answer (score 1):

Given the small size of the board a breadth-first exhaustive search is something you should be considering.  8 x 8 means only 64 squares, x8 moves (or 4 if you don't permit diagonals) and the total search is pretty small.

Comment: Diagonals aren't permitted, so it is only 4 moves per square. The pathfinding is going to be repeated a very large number of times, so eking out as much efficiency as possible is important

Answer (score 1):

Dijkstra's works well to find the single shortest path. To find the second, third ... nth shortest paths, you'd need to use an extension to Dijksta's algorithm. Once a shortest path from N1, N2, N3 ... Nx is found, clone all of the intermediate nodes on that path to create nodes N2' through Nx-1'. Clone all of the entering edges on the shortest path as well except for (N1,N2') and remove edge (Nx-1,Nx). Relax all the edges into nodes on the cloned path which now represents the second fastest way of getting to the nodes on the shortest path from the previous iteration.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not really used to dealing with graphs. Could you explain exactly what you mean by "clone all of the entering edges"? So, for example say you're looking at Ni, which has edges to Ni+1, Ni-1, and two nodes that aren't on the path, A and B. What exactly would the corresponding edges for Ni' be?

I'm also not sure what "relax all the edges into nodes on the cloned path" means.

Comment: Sure. Let's say the first iteration of Dijkstra's algorithm found a shortest path N1, N2, N3 ... Nx where N1 is the starting node and Nx is the finishing node. You start by cloning node N2 to create N2'. You also clone any entering edge of N2 so that for each edge (?,N2) in the original graph, you now have an edge (?,N2') in the modified graph. The one exception is that you do not clone the edge (N1, N2) to create (N1, N2'). Continuing in next comment ...

Comment: Now you relax all the edges into N2'. In the context of Dijkstra's algorithm, relaxing an edge means updating the distance to the head (shortest known path) if the distance to the tail plus the cost of the edge is less than the existing distance to the head. At this point, the shortest path from N1 to N2' represents the second shortest path from N1 to N2. Now, repeat the process for the other intermediate nodes N3 .. Nx-1 to create nodes N3' .. Nx-1'. At each step, clone all of the entering edges except the one that was on the original shortest path (ex. create (N2',N3') rather than (N2,N3'))

Answer (score 0):

Check out [k-shortest paths](http://code.google.com/p/k-shortest-paths/), an open-source implementation that also includes some references.